# Did "AND" and "OR" will work in same query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I was using a query in which it has both "and" and "or" logic.Here is my query,

```
select * 
from products_event  
where products_event.active > 0 
      and is_event_activated > 0 
      and is_user_activated > 0 
      and quantity > 0  
      and  products_event.name like '%" . $search_keyword . "%' 
      or products_event.short_desc like '%" . $search_keyword . "%'
```

I am getting a result but it also list the products which are having '0' as value for active column and so on.

The php my admin also  not showing any error in the query.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add brackets. Try this:

```
select * 
from products_event  
where products_event.active > 0 
      and is_event_activated > 0 
      and is_user_activated > 0 
      and quantity > 0  
      and  
      (products_event.name like '%" . $search_keyword . "%' 
      or products_event.short_desc like '%" . $search_keyword . "%')
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to respect the precedence of logical operators. `and` has precedence over `or`, as in multiplication has precedence over addition in math. Brackets make sure that your `or` condition is satisfied first.

Your first query is also syntatically correct, so it is only natural that you don't see any errors.

```
select * 
from products_event  
where products_event.active > 0 
  and is_event_activated > 0 
  and is_user_activated > 0 
  and quantity > 0  
  and  
  (products_event.name like '%" . $search_keyword . "%' 
  or products_event.short_desc like '%" . $search_keyword . "%')
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL (and normally in all the logic processors) **And** has precedence over **Or**, so if you do:

```
Where A and B or C
```

it would be executed as

```
Where (A and B) or C
```

So, to avoid confusions and improve readability it's always recommended to use brackets when using multiple different conditions.